# put a div at the bottom of a parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am struggling with this :

I would like to put a div ( red in my code ) at the bottom of another div.

The div should be stick to the bottom of the parent div.

```css
    .homepage-wrapper{ 
        max-width: 1028px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto; 
        }
    .homepage-top-category-container-title{
        background-color: black;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
        }
    #homepage-top-category-container-title{
        color: orange;
        }
    .homepage-top-category-container-list{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap:wrap;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        background-color: yellow; 
        }
    .homepage-top-category-container-item{
        display: block;
        float: none;
        width: auto;
        height:auto;
        border: solid 1px black;
    }
    #homepage-top-category-container-item-a{
     width: 240px;
     height: 360px;
     }
    #homepage-top-category-container-item-b{
     margin-left: 20px;
     width: 240px;
     height: 360px;
     }
    #homepage-top-category-container-item-c{
     margin-left: 20px;
     width: 240px;
     height: 360px;
     }
    #homepage-top-category-container-item-d{
     margin-left: 20px;
     width: 240px;
     height: 360px;
     }
    .test{
     position:relative;
     bottom:0;
     background-color: red;
     }
```

```html
    <div class="homepage-wrapper">
        <div class="homepage-top-category-container">
            <div class="homepage-top-category-container-title">
                <span id="homepage-top-category-container-title">Most popular aisles</span>
            </div>
            <div class="homepage-top-category-container-list">
                
                <div class="homepage-top-category-container-item" id="homepage-top-category-container-item-a">
                    block A
                    <div class="test">
         button
                    </div>               
                </div> 
                <div class="homepage-top-category-container-item" id="homepage-top-category-container-item-b">
        block B
                </div>
                <div class="homepage-top-category-container-item" id="homepage-top-category-container-item-c">
        block C
                </div>
                <div class="homepage-top-category-container-item" id="homepage-top-category-container-item-d">
        block D
               </div>
            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I will appreciate any help from our community. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you used `flex`, then use it again and add `margin`s to the `button` to make it simple:

```css
.homepage-wrapper{ 
        max-width: 1028px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto; 
        }
    .homepage-top-category-container-title{
        background-color: black;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
        }
    #homepage-top-category-container-title{
        color: orange;
        }
    .homepage-top-category-container-list{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap:wrap;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        background-color: yellow; 
        }
    .homepage-top-category-container-item{
        display: block;
        float: none;
        width: auto;
        height:auto;
        border: solid 1px black;
    }
    #homepage-top-category-container-item-a{
     width: 240px;
     height: 360px;
      display:flex;/* added */
      flex-flow:column;/* added */
     }
    #homepage-top-category-container-item-b{
     margin-left: 20px;
     width: 240px;
     height: 360px;
     }
    #homepage-top-category-container-item-c{
     margin-left: 20px;
     width: 240px;
     height: 360px;
     }
    #homepage-top-category-container-item-d{
     margin-left: 20px;
     width: 240px;
     height: 360px;
     }
    .test{
      margin-top:auto;/* added */
      margin-bottom:0;/* added */
        background-color: red;
     }
```

```html
<div class="homepage-wrapper">
        <div class="homepage-top-category-container">
            <div class="homepage-top-category-container-title">
                <span id="homepage-top-category-container-title">Most popular aisles</span>
            </div>
            <div class="homepage-top-category-container-list">
                
                <div class="homepage-top-category-container-item" id="homepage-top-category-container-item-a">
                    block A
                  <p>paragraph</p>
                    <div class="test">
         button
                    </div>               
                </div> 
                <div class="homepage-top-category-container-item" id="homepage-top-category-container-item-b">
        block B
                </div>
                <div class="homepage-top-category-container-item" id="homepage-top-category-container-item-c">
        block C
                </div>
                <div class="homepage-top-category-container-item" id="homepage-top-category-container-item-d">
        block D
               </div>
            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So the idea is to set `margin-top:auto` to button to push it all the way down, other sides can be having any value.

If you set `auto` for all 4 sides, then it will stand in the middle of the empty area (demo in snippet below).

```css
.homepage-wrapper{ 
        max-width: 1028px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto; 
        }
    .homepage-top-category-container-title{
        background-color: black;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
        }
    #homepage-top-category-container-title{
        color: orange;
        }
    .homepage-top-category-container-list{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap:wrap;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        background-color: yellow; 
        }
    .homepage-top-category-container-item{
        display: block;
        float: none;
        width: auto;
        height:auto;
        border: solid 1px black;
    }
    #homepage-top-category-container-item-a{
     width: 240px;
     height: 360px;
      display:flex;/* added */
      flex-flow:column;/* added */
     }
    #homepage-top-category-container-item-b{
     margin-left: 20px;
     width: 240px;
     height: 360px;
     }
    #homepage-top-category-container-item-c{
     margin-left: 20px;
     width: 240px;
     height: 360px;
     }
    #homepage-top-category-container-item-d{
     margin-left: 20px;
     width: 240px;
     height: 360px;
     }
    .test{
      margin:auto;/* added */
        background-color: red;
     }
```

```html
<div class="homepage-wrapper">
        <div class="homepage-top-category-container">
            <div class="homepage-top-category-container-title">
                <span id="homepage-top-category-container-title">Most popular aisles</span>
            </div>
            <div class="homepage-top-category-container-list">
                
                <div class="homepage-top-category-container-item" id="homepage-top-category-container-item-a">
                    block A
                  <p>paragraph</p>
                    <div class="test">
         button
                    </div>               
                </div> 
                <div class="homepage-top-category-container-item" id="homepage-top-category-container-item-b">
        block B
                </div>
                <div class="homepage-top-category-container-item" id="homepage-top-category-container-item-c">
        block C
                </div>
                <div class="homepage-top-category-container-item" id="homepage-top-category-container-item-d">
        block D
               </div>
            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the parent's position to relative, and the child's position to absolute. https://jsfiddle.net/yak613/d43eytfb/

```
.homepage-wrapper{ 
    max-width: 1028px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
    }
.homepage-top-category-container-title{
    background-color: black;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
    }
#homepage-top-category-container-title{
    color: orange;
    }
.homepage-top-category-container-list{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: yellow; 
    }
.homepage-top-category-container-item{
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    height:auto;
    border: solid 1px black;
    position: relative;

}
#homepage-top-category-container-item-a{
    width: 240px;
    height: 360px;
    }
#homepage-top-category-container-item-b{
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 240px;
    height: 360px;
    }
#homepage-top-category-container-item-c{
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 240px;
    height: 360px;
    }
#homepage-top-category-container-item-d{
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 240px;
    height: 360px;
    }
.test{
    position:absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    bottom:0;
    background-color: red;
    }
```

Comment: To add to this, I would explain that `position: relative` creates a new positioning context inside the element affected, and the position of elements with `position: absolute` on them is calculated in relation to the positioning context they're descendant of. (I.e the closest matching element set to `position: relative` or the `body` element). A detailed explanation [can be found here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/css-positioning)

Comment: Yes ! it works. This lttle tweak solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To stick an element to bottom of its parent

```
#elem{
   position: absolute:
   bottom: 0;
}
```

But if it is a footer you must set parent height so go to the end screen.